# Advanced Animation eBooks or Tutorials

Tags: animation, directx

Can anyone help me find some eBooks or tutorials on advanced animation techniques?
I am looking for something that covers subjects like layered animation, blending, mixing, procedural animation, morphing etc. Something like Advanced Animation with DirectX 8 by Jim Adams.